# Adding a "processed" flag to a Drupal Webform, that admins can use to indicate whether or not they've dealt with a particular submission?

Tags: webforms

We're using a Drupal Webform to accept customer requests for a free "kit" that we will mail them.

This works fine on the submission side, but we'd like a simple way to look at the submissions and tell which ones have been fulfilled, and which have not.

So far, I haven't been able to come up with a field that is visible *and* editable by administrators viewing the results, but not also shown to the customer when they are filling it out.

I realize I could put a checkbox on the form for "fulfilled", and then hide it from the customer with CSS... but I'm hoping there's a better way. Is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a similar thing where two fields are marked as Private and these are only seen by admins.

[image]
[image]
[image]

We also only allow authenticated users to submit these type of forms.

[image]

Comment: Bingo, this is exactly what I was looking for. Just missed the "private" checkbox somehow!

Comment: To help test out different user permissions, also check in with the masquerade module https://www.drupal.org/project/masquerade -- great addition to dev and stage servers. That may help view the form to ensure normal authenticated users can't see the administrative fields and yet ensure that admins can.